# Make a class open, but internal

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, module, access-modifiers

I have a class:

```
internal class A {

}
```

I also have another class:

```
open class B: A {

}
```

I really need `B` to be `open`, but in order for this code to compile, I have to make `A` open, but making `A` `open` also makes it `public` and I don't want that.

Do you think if there's any way to make a class `internal open`?

Comment: Maybe use `protocol` conformance and composition or delegation

Comment: Yeah... What a pickle...

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg You could maybe make `A` `public`, and add an `internal` init and then a `public` one marked unavailable. Then `A` is visible, but an instance of it cannot be created from outside.

Comment: @George oh that's a one solution, thank you

Comment: Yeah, that's at least **some** access control... Epic

Comment: While I upvoted your own answer - any chance you can put more detail in your question? Seriously, it's lacking **why** this type of code design is required.

Comment: @dfd No, honestly, it's a completely arbitrary question that doesn't have anything to do with real life, just a random 3 AM shower thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the closest you can get to what you want:

```
open class A {
    public let message: String

    fileprivate init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }
}

open class B: A {
    public override init(message: String) {
        super.init(message: message)
    }

    public func printMessage() {
        print(message)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let b = B(message: "Hello world!")
b.printMessage()
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to have the `init` in `B` inherited, because then it must be in `A`. But you also can't mark the `init` in `A` as `@available(*, unavailable)`, otherwise it is unavailable to `B` too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not, Swift doesn't support this scenario.

The design of the language involves making other overridable declarations in `A` to be visible in `B` in another module without explicitly redefining them. They need to be publicly visible/overrideable on `A` if they are to be visible on `B` and thus the entire class must be visible/overridable.